# Accessing of Webview from Mainactivity

Tags: android

I have an MainActivity with one ImageButton & Second activity with one webview .I have to load url in second activiti's webview on clicking ImageButton.

Comment: just do this in imageButton onclicklistener start  an intente with extras and in the extras add your url and in second activity get the intente extras and and set url to webview

Answer (score 0):

Implement `onClickListner` on `ImageButton` of `MainActivity`

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and load Url in second activity
 `mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this 
In the first Activity imageButton onclicklistener event

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
 myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
 CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

And this in the second Activity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String value = intent.getStringExtra("key"); 
    mWebview  = new WebView(this);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    mWebview .loadUrl(value );
    setContentView(mWebview );
   }
```